# Lightning Out : getting "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" from Heroku App

Tags: heroku, lightning-out, cors

**---------- THE EXPLANATION ----------**
I need to use my **LWC**'s in an **External Site**. For it I use [Lightning Out](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lightning_out), and I want to test it with [Heroku App](https://www.heroku.com/home).
I have built a simple Aura Application according to documentation here : [Lightning Out Dependencies](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.lightning_out_dependencies)

```html
<aura:application access="Global"  extends="ltng:outApp" >
    <aura:dependency resource="c:ltng_out_testLwc"/>
</aura:application>
```

The `ltng_out_testLwc` is simple LWC without complex logic:

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Test LWC" icon-name="utility:print">
        Test LWC
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Then I've created a simple **Heroku App** with connecting it to my **Github** private repository, following the instructions here:
[[10 Step Guide] How to deploy HTML on Heroku app the quick and easy way!](https://consultantsussex.com/deploy-html-on-heroku/)

Where I have a simple `index.html` page, which should show my LWC.

**I have not implemented logic for obtaining the access token from the Heroku App** (Could it be the issue ?)
So I obtain the access token in Postman, and then hardcode it in the App:

[image]

The Lightning domain I take from (In Lightning) **Setup** => **Company Settings** => **My Domain** => **My Domain Name**

[image]

And then build it in next way :  "https://" + **My Domain Name** + ".my.salesforce.com"

The Code for the page (in order to show it here I changed the **exact domain** to "**my-domain**", and I changed the **Access Token** to "**access-token**" ):

```html
<div id="lightning"></div>
<script src="https://my-domain.my.salesforce.com/lightning/lightning.out.js"></script>
<script>
    $Lightning.use("c:LightningOutDemo",
        function() {
            $Lightning.createComponent(
                "c:ltng_out_testLwc", 
                {},
                "lightning",
                function(cmp) {
                    console.log("LWC component was created");
                }
            );
        },
        'https://my-domain.my.salesforce.com',
        'access-token'
    );
</script>
```

For **Access Token** I have created a **Connected App** and I take it from there.

[image]

I have added my **Heroku App origin** to **CORS** and enabled it :

[image]

Also I have added my **Heroku App origin** to **CSP Trusted Sites**

[image]

and to **Remote Site Settings**

[image]

**---------- THE ERROR ----------**

**However I am still getting the following error** (in order to show it here I changed my **Heroku App Name** to **heroku-app**) :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://my-domain.my.salesforce.com/c/LightningOutDemo.app?aura.format=JSON&aura.formatAdapter=LIGHTNING_OUT' from origin 'https://heroku-app.herokuapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

**Browser Console** :

[image]

So I am getting the **401** response :

[image]

It **does work** if I use it in a **Visualforce Page** with **Lightning Out**.

Example of code for it  :

```html
<apex:page >
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <div id="lightning" />
    <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:lightningOutDemo", function () {
            $Lightning.createComponent("c:ltng_out_testLwc",
                {  },
                "lightning",
                function (cmp) {
                    console.log("LWC component was created");
                }
            );
        });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

**I have read a lot of articles and questions about it** (some of them listed below). However **none of them** helped me.

[Lightning Out : Error 404, Blocked by CORS](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/285710/lightning-out-error-404-blocked-by-cors)
[Lightning Out : Error 404, Blocked by CORS developer forum](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000XnesQAC)
[CORS issue with lightning out used in external website](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/173271/cors-issue-with-lightning-out-used-in-external-website)
[Lightning Out: CORS error even after whitelisting force.com site](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/254557/lightning-out-cors-error-even-after-whitelisting-force-com-site)
[Lightning Out session expired from external page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/161417/lightning-out-session-expired-from-external-page/237897#237897)
[lightning out gives "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000QzaTQAS)
[Use Lightning Web Components in External Website – Lightning Out](https://newstechnologystuff.com/2019/05/28/use-lightning-web-components-in-lightning-out/)
[Cross-origin resource sharing(CORS) and Salesforce APIs](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/cross-origin-resource-sharingcors-salesforce-apis-josu%C3%A9-nogueira/)

I hope that someone has already **faced** and **resolved** this issue.

*Any help will be appreciated.*

*Thank you*

Comment: How are you obtaining the access token and also the lightning domain URL? Are you doing an Oauth? Can you share the code for your Oauth?

Comment: Hi @MohithShrivastava, thanks for reaching out. 
I have not implemented logic for obtaining the access token from the Heroku App (Could it be the issue ?)
So I obtain the access token in Postman, and then hardcode it in the App. 
The Lightning domain I take from (In Lightning) Setup => Company Settings => My Domain => My Domain Name. 
And then build it in next way : "https://" + My Domain Name + ".my.salesforce.com".
Could any of those cause the issue ?
Thanks.

Comment: Definitely any of those can be an issue

Comment: Take a look at here for comprehensive example https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Learning-Salesforce-Lightning-Application-Development/tree/master/chapter10

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Thanks, I could not find a good Lightning Out example with Authentication. Will try to implement it.

Comment: Notice that the lightning domain is not my domain of the org.there are examples for authenticated and unauthenticated both there in that repo. Something to be mindful to look into ltngOutApp folder only for authenticated experience

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will take it in mind.

Comment: I don't think you used enough arrows...

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Thank you so much, I have looked into your example , added the an Oauth Authentication and it works now.

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks, I will keep it in mind.

Comment: @VitaliiDehnerys I have added as an answer to help others!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here could be due to any of below

1. The OAuth token is incorrect
2. The lightning domain you have is incorrect. It typically ends with `lightning.force.com` and not same as myDomain as you have in the code.

To see a comprehensive example of how to do this, checkout this git [repo](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Learning-Salesforce-Lightning-Application-Development/tree/master/chapter10)

Using the [forcejs](https://github.com/ccoenraets/forcejs) kit you can check an example shown [here](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Learning-Salesforce-Lightning-Application-Development/tree/master/chapter10/ltngOutApp)

Comment: It resolved my issue, thanks again.